What Linux command to execute AND write a new line \n in a python file?
I want execute a Unix command to create a python file, it is to execute a long script that executes normal python things (like read a file or frame) and interact with the Unix shell, (the reason why I use subprocess instead print).
Expected output in the file:
import subprocess
for i in range(3):
    if i>1:
        subprocess.run(['echo', 'first sentence.\n'])
    else:
        subprocess.run(['echo', 'second sentence.\n'])

The goal is to see this in my shell:
second sentence
second sentence
first sentence

So I write this command like that this:
echo "import subprocess\nfor i in range(3):\n\tif i>1:\n\t\tsubprocess.run(['echo', 'first sentence.\\n'])\n\telse:\n\t\tsubprocess.run(['echo', 'second sentence.\\n'])" > script.py

So the shell understands "Okay, I have a \n here, so execute a new line in the file. And here, I have a \\n, so I write a \n in the file instead execute it". I use ' instead of " because the string to be echoed is enclosed within "'s. If I use ", it does not understand where the content begins and where it ends.
But I get this result in my python file, which obviously produces an error when I execute script.py:
import subprocess
for i in range(3):
    if i>1:
        subprocess.run(['echo', 'first sentence.
'])
    else:
        subprocess.run(['echo', 'second sentence.
'])

The cmd understand my \\n exactly like \n so execute instead write the new line.
I tried with the -e option of echo, but the result is the same.
Does someone know if it is possible to execute, and write, a \n?
Note:
I use a Kali Linux, and version 3 of Python.

When I run your command echo "import subprocess\nfor i in range(3):\n\tif i>1:\n\t\tsubprocess('echo', 'first sentence\\n')\n\telse:\n\t\tsubprocess('echo', 'second sentence\\n')" > script.py, the output is different: It contains ' instead of ". Please [edit] your question and copy&paste both the command and the resulting output. Please also show the expected output. BTW: Kali is a specialized distribution for experts. It might be easier to use a general purpose distribution like Ubuntu or Debian.

That's not how you use the subprocess module. You should be calling subprocess.run(), and the argument is either a single string (with the shell=True option) or a list of strings. Please show actual working code.

Using echo to produce the Python script is a poor choice, since the behaviour of echo is inconsistent across the different heritages of Unix - some shells have built-in echo that expands such escapes (as yours evidently does), whilst others simply print the string you give them:
$ dash -c 'echo "foo\n"'
foo

$ bash -c 'echo "foo\n"'
foo\n
$

You could explicitly use the platform's echo:
/bin/echo "import subprocess"$'\n' "for …"

I would recommend using printf instead, as its result is more predictable.
For example:
printf '%s\n' \
       'import subprocess' \
       'for i in range(3):' \
       '    if i>1:' \
       "        subprocess('echo', 'first sentence\n')" \
       '    else:' \
       "        subprocess('echo', 'second sentence\n')" |
    python

This produces the expected result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

And if we fix the Python errors:
printf '%s\n' \
       'import subprocess' \
       'for i in range(3):' \
       '    if i>1:' \
       "        subprocess.run(('echo', 'first sentence\n')" \
       '    else:' \
       "        subprocess.run(('echo', 'second sentence\n'))" |
    python

Then we get the desired result:
second sentence

second sentence

first sentence



Alternatively, and probably more legibly, just use a here-document:
python <<END 
import subprocess
for i in range(3):
    if i>1:
        subprocess.run(('echo', 'first sentence\n'))
    else:
        subprocess.run(('echo', 'second sentence\n'))
END

If you have no substitutions to expand, prefer using a single-quoted here-document (<<'END') for simplicity and safety.

the escape sequence is processed by python, it's not sent to the shell, so it doesn't matter if echo processes escape sequences or not.

@Barmar, it absolutely does matter - because when echo expands it to newline, it becomes invalid Python.  Ah, I see you're talking about the echo within the Python script - I'm talking about the outer one that provides the input to Python.  I'll make that clearer.

You will want to quote the string after  << to prevent the shell from processing backticks, dollar signs, or backslashes in the here document.

@tripleee, there are no backquotes or dollar signs in this here-document (and it's likely from the context that we would want shell variables expanded - in which case, we'd want \$ to work).

As a general guidance, probably use (the equivalent of) single quotes around here documents unless you specifically want the shell to perform these substitutions. You'll see the backslash handling in action if you put in a double backslash; it will come out as single.

@tripleee, I've added that recommendation now.
